# MySQL SELECT FROM TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have got a `TABLE` like:

```
 id | names | fav_color
|------------------------
|1  | John  | black
|2  | Isaac | orange
|3  | Ruth  | blue
|4  | Ezra  | black
|5  | Luke  | orange
|6  | Acts  | blue
|7  | Apoca | black
|8  | James | orange
|9  | Roma  | yellow
```

I want a Query that will `SELECT all` the `fav_colors` but return them distinctively with no duplicates.

Something like

```
fav_color
---------
black
orange
blue
yellow
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fav_color FROM tablename;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8306/1)

This will give you something like:

```
| FAV_COLOR |
-------------
|     black |
|    orange |
|      blue |
|    yellow |
```

Answer (score 1):

Mahmoud has given you the correct answer. Should you want to know the number of rows for each `fav_color` you could do:

```
SELECT fav_color, COUNT(*) AS count FROM tablename GROUP BY fav_color;
```

This will output:

```
fav_color|count
--------- -----
black     3 
orange    3
blue      2
yellow    1
```